# Подсчет разных значений

Tags: oracle, plsql, select, sql

Добрый вечер, господа!

Прошу помощи...

Есть таблица:

```
name   status   amount
-----------------------
val1   1        45643
val2   2        32115
val3   1        46431
val4   2        23366
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как в селекте ниже вывести 2 колонки, в одной посчитать amount для status = 1, во второй - для status = 2. В селекте считается общий amount. Можно ли сделать требуемый подсчет без вложенных селектов?

```
select name, date, etc, wtf,
sum(case when status !=1 then 1 else 0 end) as "2_count",
sum(amount) as "all_amount"
from foo, wtf, mega_table
where
/* over 9000 разных условий и связей тут */
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name, date, etc, wtf,
sum(case when status =1 then amount else 0 end) as "status_1",
sum(case when status =2 then amount else 0 end) as "status_2",
sum(amount) as "all_amount"
from foo, wtf, mega_table
```

Comment: Запилить amount в then...
Все гениальное просто!

Большое спасибо!

Comment: Не за что. Это стандартный приём.

Answer (score 0):

```
select (select  sum(amount) from table where status = 1) as '1',
    (select  sum(amount) from table where status = 2) as '2'
```

Comment: А без вложенных селектов это возможно сделать?
Например есть селект уже с условиями которые нужны и уже описаны во where:

select name, date, etc, wtf
sum(case when status !=1 then 1 else 0 end) as all_count
sum(amount) as all_amount
from foo, wtf, mega_table
where
/* over 9000 разных условий и связей тут */